# Update URL with new parameter value

Tags: javascript, url

I needed a way to update a parameter in the URL, or add it if it doesn't exist, but keep any other variables the same value.  I built this function to do the task, and while it works, I feel like it's taking longer than it should.  Does anyone have any suggestion on what I could change or a faster method?

```
function changeURLParameter(sVariable, sNewValue)
{
    var aURLParams = [];
    var aParts;
    var aParams = (window.location.search).substring(1, (window.location.search).length).split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < aParams.length; i++)
    {
        aParts = aParams[i].split('=');
        aURLParams[aParts[0]] = aParts[1];
    }

    if (aURLParams[sVariable] != sNewValue)
    {
        if (sNewValue.toUpperCase() == "ALL")
            aURLParams[sVariable] = null;
        else
            aURLParams[sVariable] = sNewValue;

        var sNewURL = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
        var bFirst = true;

        for (var sKey in aURLParams)
        {
            if (aURLParams[sKey])
            {
                if (bFirst)
                {
                    sNewURL += "?" + sKey + "=" + aURLParams[sKey];
                    bFirst = false;
                }
                else
                    sNewURL += "&" + sKey + "=" + aURLParams[sKey];
            }
        }

        return sNewURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realise that you can use update "window.location.search" (because window is read/write) so you don't need to grab the origin and pathname. EX: window.location.search = "?name=wolf";

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about ways to improve performance, but I did notice a couple things.

**Guaranteed Returns**

If the specified key is already set to the specified value, your function does not return anything. Maybe this is the expected behavior, but I could see it being a problem if you used the function to directly update the URL.

```
window.location.href = changeURLParameter("thriggle","boring");
// If thriggle already == boring, this redirects you to /undefined
```

One way to fix that would be to simply remove the If statement `if (aURLParams[sVariable] != sNewValue){...}`.

Without that check, regardless of whether the parameter is already set to the specified value, it'll be overwritten with the desired value and the URL string will be returned.

**Original Sin**

`window.location.origin` does not exist in older versions of Internet Explorer (9 and down). If your user base doesn't overlap with those poor souls still using IE9, feel free to ignore this one, but otherwise you could do something like this:

```
var sOrigin = window.location.origin ? window.location.origin : window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
sNewUrl = sOrigin + window.location.pathname;
```

Edit: even better, as you noted in your followup comment, just update `window.location.search` directly and you won't have to deal with `window.location.origin`!

Comment: Oh yes, I botched that up. If the value is the same then you don't need to update the URL and can skip the rebuild.  When I made this code it was for a specific case but then I turned it into a general function.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you should split the problem into separate pieces.

1. You want to add/change a parameter
2. So you need to get the current parameters
3. So you need to parse the current query string (aka `location.search`)
4. And then you need to pack the params back into a query string

Right now, you're doing all that in one function, but I'd split that up into several.

First the parsing: Now, this can is actually be quite tricky, depending on how deep you want to go. Firstly, there's the URL encoding scheme (a literal `&` becomes `%26`, etc.).

Then there's the fact that any key can occur any number of times in a query string (e.g. `foo=1&foo=2`), and how to handle that. Usually, you want to match the behavior of the server on this point. Often, the last value for the key "wins", while adding brackets to the key (e.g. `foo[]=1&foo[]=2`) is means it's interpreted as a `foo = [1, 2]` array. This is however an informal syntax, and different servers act differently. Point is, there's ambiguity at play.

Right now, I'll go with the naïve solution: Don't unescape params, don't parse arrays.

```
function getQueryParameters() {
  var queryString = location.search.slice(1),
      params = {};

  queryString.replace(/([^=]*)=([^&]*)&*/g, function (_, key, value) {
    params[key] = value;
  });

  return params;
}
```

I'm using `replace` here instead of splitting the string. Basically matching keys and values in the string, one pair at a time.

Next up, setting query parameters. Again, a naïve solution that assumes that values have been encoded properly already, and doesn't bother with arrays.

```
function setQueryParameters(params) {
  var query = [],
      key, value;

  for(key in params) {
    if(!params.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    value = params[key];
    query.push(key + "=" + value);
  }

  location.search = query.join("&");
}
```

And so finally, to change a param, you can do something like

```
var params = getQueryParameters();

if(params.foo != "new value") {
  params.foo = "new value";
  setQueryParameters(params);
}
```

Again, this is all pretty simplistic, but it's mostly about the structure of it all.

Comment: Just one remark: There is no such thing as "array-type values". `foo[]=1&foo[]=2` is just two times the same parameter that happens to have `[]` as part of the key. Just because certain server-side languages interpret them as arrays doesn't generally make it so.

Comment: @RoToRa True, it's an informal syntax. I'll tweak the text.